# How to get the size of a list ( where list is a M2M map between class)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
@Entity
public class EUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<UserRole> roles;


        //getters and setters method here

}


@Entity
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String roleName;


        //getters and setters method here
}
```

now using the service i am trying to see the size of `roles` list

```
EUser approveUser = (EUser) userService.getOne(2);
System.out.println(approveUser.getRoles().size());
```

but I am getting the following error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/Ebajar] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.ebajar.model.EUser.roles, no session or session was closed] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.ebajar.model.EUser.roles, no session or session was closed
```

How to solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your EUser Entity class to

```
@Entity
public class EUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id; 
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<UserRole> roles;


        //getters and setters method here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

let me explain it to you:

As `spring` will create a `sessionFactory` which related `DB connection session`, in debugging mode when you `eager` to fetch data from database, it can do it as the database session did not closed.

But when you do in `lazily`, pitifully `session` already closed and you can not get data from it. what's more, you will get `no session or session was closed`, I also had got this `ERROR` at the first time I got in touch with `spring` and `hibernate`, which puzzled me for a very long time.

I think the essential problem is that, you do not have session maintainer to keep your session alived while you are just debugging and have no `struts` or `springmvc`.

To solve this, I think There are three ways:
1. Do the  debugging with the whole framework includes session maintainer, which is so slow and heavy!.
2. Add a session filter into web.xml:

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>session</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name> session </filter-name>
    <url-pattern> /* </url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

which will maintain your session with database.
3. Or you could use `Mocked` testing method that imitate what session maintainer doing.

At the end, I will not suggest you with setting all type with `eager`, because this could eliminate the performance of your application. Even if it is not significant in testing stage, but to imitate real environment in testing stage is important.

Comment: i tried using the second method. still getting the same error

Comment: @LynAs then you can use `mocked` testing method,please search for `spring-mock`